# Polymer google-maps element not displaying

Tags: html, google-maps, google-api, polymer

I was watching some of the polymer videos from Google I/O the other day, and when I got to the part where they used a `google-map` element, no matter what I tried it would not display. Later trying to get it to work, I discovered that if I set the `google-map` element to `display: block` and added a height and width to it, it would display. I did not find anything in the documentation about this. Also, even after this, the map-marker elements will not display. Should I just file a bug? Or is there an easy fix?

Comment: visit this page [link](http://io2014codelabs.appspot.com/static/codelabs/polymer-build-maps/#2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the demo page: [https://github.com/PolymerLabs/google-map/blob/master/demo.html#L21:L23](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/google-map/blob/master/demo.html#L21%3aL23)

The maps api requires the container the map is in to be fixed height and `display: block`. The map should probably set a default height but the docs also show this: http://polymerlabs.github.io/google-map/components/google-map/#google-map

Comment: I suggest that you add this to the hello world sample on polymer-project.org under "Use Elements (30 sec)". The 2 lines in the sample now won't do the job as `<google-map lat="37.790" long="-122.390"></google-map>` is missing the `fit` property; so the map won't show. And new comers may not figure it out in less than 30 sec :) plus, the sample should work as is! :)

Comment: The links have died - see e.g. https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/blob/master/demo/index.html for the demo